# Laravel - Passing Request methode to job not working

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pass the $request to Jobs inside laravel, but it doesn't work

Controller:

```
EunoS::dispatch($request->all())->delay(now());
```

Inside Job:

```
protected $request;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($request)
{
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
        $request = $this->$request;
}
```

Error log:

```
ErrorException: Undefined variable: request in /var/www/html/sd/app/Jobs/EunoS.php:43
```

Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access properties on a object, you dont have to use the second `$` sign.

```
$request = $this->$request;
```

Should be

```
$request = $this->request;
```